# Changing the units for an independent variable in a Poisson model

Tags: poisson-distribution, units

I'm trying to model a dose-response relationship between the incidence of cancer (dependent variable, counts) and the radiation dose (independent variable in gray). Can I change the unit of the independent variable from gray to milligray (gray × 1000) and have the same response?

I have built two models, 1 with independent variable as gray, and the second model with gray × 1000 as the independent variable. Should the model have similar parameter estimates, just different by a factor of 1000? 
I have tried this, and my parameter for dose-response in two separate models goes from 1.000764 per milligray to 2.14 per gray.

Comment: Wouldn't a milligray be gray $\div$ 1000? I think gray × 1000 = kilogray.

Comment: @NickStauner indeed, but the recorded values in milligrays are the values in grays multiplied by 1000. So if you had 0.32 grays, you now record 320 milligrays. If you named your data column "grays" (unsurprisingly, since the measurements were in that unit) and you make a new column called "milligrays", you may well say something like 'milligrays=grays$\times$1000' ... perhaps somewhat confusingly, but the result is as it should be.

Comment: Oh, of course! Man, this reminds me of other mistakes I made in college physics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear predictor is on a log scale, and $\frac{\log 2.14}{\log 1.000764} \approx 1000$. The response is modelled by a Poisson distribution whose mean increases by a *factor* of $1.000764$ for a 1 mGy increase in radiation dose, or equivalently a *factor* of $1.000764^{1000}=2.14$ for a 1 Gy increase.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something else is wrong if your parameter changes by a different factor than your units. Here's a simple simulation in R to demonstrate that, as you suspect, multiplying your predictor by 1000 should change the scale of your parameter by the same factor (dividing it):

```
y=rpois(10000,1);x=rnorm(10000,5);x1000=x*1000    #Generates random count and continuous data
summary(glm(y~x,family='poisson'))$coefficients   #fits Poisson GLM of counts ~ continuous IV

               Estimate  Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.07375024 0.050409708  1.463017 0.1434629
x           -0.01275800 0.009894814 -1.289363 0.1972721

summary(glm(y~x1000,family='poisson'))$coefficients       #same as above, using multiplied IV

                Estimate   Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.073750238 5.040971e-02  1.463017 0.1434629 #intercept stats unchanged
x1000       -0.000012758 9.894814e-06 -1.289363 0.1972721 #Estimate and SE differ by x10^(-3)
```